# The size of an structure

Tags: c, struct, size, malloc, structure

I have a structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char fname[100], lname[100];
    int age, salary;
} *employer;
```

And now, I want a pointer variable *empl1* that contains enough space for 100 employees:

```
employer empl1 = malloc(100 * sizeof(employer));
```

The problem is that **sizeof(employer)** is **4** *(the size of a pointer on my machine)*.
How I get the size of all *employer* structure? *(208 in my case).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an *invalid* (untenable) use of `typedef struct`, s/b `typedef struct ... employer;` (no asterisk/pointer)

I would also recommend that you do:

```
typedef struct {
   char fname[100];
   char lname[100];
   int age;
   int salary;
} employer;
```

Comment: Yes, your typedef shouldn't resolve to a pointer (and it's usual to `type` each item in your struct).

Comment: The type definition is syntactically valid (it creates a struct type with no name, only the pointer type derived from it has a name). But I'm in the "don't typedef pointers" camp so I agree it's a bad idea.

Comment: It's going to be so difficult to do anything with the pointer version that it's nearly unusable (IMNSHO)

Comment: Ok, thanks to all. PS. Why you recomande me to write a single variable after a datatype?

Comment: You *could* use `sizeof *empl1`. And that's what the Standard Malloc Advice would say to use anyway. Still I like to see structs with names.

Comment: @MariusMarusanici. Writing a single variable after a datatype is for human readability and maintainability purposes. It is generally easier to track and trace if an issue occurs.